# count post with all categories in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

hello I have two tables one is categories another is ads_listings. In categories table there are 4 columns id, parent_category_id, category_slug, category_title. Here parent_category_id 0 indicates main category and rest of the thing indicates sub category. user post store in ads_listings table. Now I want to find post with specific categories like this

```
vehicles(3)
cars(2)
motorbike(1)
cycle(0)
```

here the problem is my code found only subcategories which have posts. my controller code is

```
public function countListingsByCategories()
{
    return DB::table("ads_listings")
        ->select("categories.category_title",DB::raw("COUNT(ads_listings.category_id) as num_listings"))
        ->join("categories", "categories.id","=","ads_listings.category_id")
        ->groupBy("ads_listings.category_id")
        ->get();
}
```

views code is:

```
<ul class="row catelist">
  @if(isset($categoriesNumListings) && count($categoriesNumListings))      
     @foreach($categoriesNumListings as $categoriesNumListings)          
        <li class="col-md-12"><a href="{{ route('view.listings.by.category', $categoriesNumListings->category_title) }}" title="{{ $categoriesNumListings->category_title }} ads from {{ $categoriesNumListings->category_title }}">{{ $categoriesNumListings->category_title }} <span>({{ $categoriesNumListings->num_listings }}Listings )</span></a></li>
    @endforeach
  @endif
</ul>
```

my Category table is:

[image: category table]

ads_listing table is:
[image: list table]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are counting ad_listings when you primarily want to count categories and get the number of ad_listings, I would do something like:

Second shot :)

```
public function countListingsByCategories()
{
    return DB::table("categories")
      ->select("categories.category_title",
        DB::raw("categories.title, 
          CASE 
            WHEN (categories.parent_id = 0) 
            THEN (SELECT count(ads_listings.category_id)  
              FROM ads_listings 
              WHERE ads_listings.category_id in 
                    (SELECT subcategory.id 
                    FROM categories subcategory
                    WHERE subcategory.parent_id = categories.id))
            ELSE (SELECT COUNT(ads_listings.category_id)  
                  FROM ads_listings 
                  WHERE ads_listings.category_id = categories.id)
            END as numberOfPosts, 
          CASE 
            WHEN (categories.parent_id = 0) 
            THEN (select 'Category') 
            ELSE (select 'subCategory')
            END as type 
        FROM categories"))
      ->get();

}
```

Comment: this code count all post with one category.In categories table stored all the categories and subcategories here parent_category_id=0 indicates main category and rest of the id indicates subcategory. category_title is the name of category. ads_listing table stored post. here is the relationship between two tables using category_id. between two table I only found category_title which have post. But I want my main category and subcategory arrange serially and beside subcategories show  post number. if no post found then show 0 and sum all the subcategories post number show beside maincategory.

Comment: can you try running just the sql in the database query editor?
SELECT categories.title, CASE WHEN (categories.parent_id = 0) ....

Comment: sql doesn't support CASE WHEN